# Microsoft Teams: Owners cannot create additional Apps after being added via ms graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have the following bug in Microsoft Teams:

Owners added via the Graph API to a newly created group cannot create additional APPs like Planner in Microsoft Teams.

We use the following graph endpoint to add owners to the group after the group has been created. The graph call is authentificated using an azure ad service principal (azure ad application) using a certificate.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_owners

The owners are added approximately 20 minutes after creation of the group as stated in this article (Wait for 15 minutes + 5 Minutes PNP Template):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams

> If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for
>   the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication
>   delays. The recommended pattern is to retry the Create team call three
>   times, with a 10 second delay between calls.

The problem doesn't occur anymore if the user is completely deleted from owers of the group and then added again via the frontend (no matter if SharePoint, Teams or Outlook).

We can reproduce the problem at any time.

**Error message**

The following error occurs when a plan is to be created via the group:

```
e2141e79-10fe-4bcc-91dc-ff1990ad86f7
Date and Time: 05.11.2018
08:34:46 Planner Version: 16.0.11026.35000
```

[image]

Additional Data:

TenantId:
1ca8bd94-3c97-4fc6-8955-bad266b43f0b

OwnerId:
1ca8bd94-3c97-4fc6-8955-bad266b43f0b

GroupId:
25fcf2d5-cecc-44b0-bd03-d6719389e446

Response Headers:

1. cache-control: 
   private, s-maxage=0
2. content-length: 
   1233
3. content-security-policy: 
   frame-ancestors 'none';
4. content-type: 
   text/html
5. date: 
   Tue, 06 Nov 2018 08:28:15 GMT
6. p3p: 
   CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
7. status: 
   403
8. strict-transport-security: 
   max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
9. x-aspnet-version: 
   4.0.30319
10. x-aspnetmvc-version: 
    5.1
11. x-content-type-options: 
    nosniff
12. x-correlationid: 
    aeaf0deb-4cab-4c67-a406-6ec6eb527ad0
13. x-frame-options: 
    Deny
14. x-msedge-ref: 
    Ref A: 368E038C7FA5468CA7805EB1C708B607 Ref B: AMS04EDGE0210 Ref C: 2018-11-06T08:28:15Z
15. x-officecluster: 
    neu-000.tasks.osi.office.net
16. x-officefe: 
    TodoFrontEndBox_IN_6
17. x-officeversion: 
    16.0.11026.35000
18. x-powered-by: 
    ASP.NET
19. x-proxycluster: 
    neu-000.tasks.osi.office.net
20. x-proxyfe: 
    TodoFrontEndBox_IN_6
21. x-proxyversion: 
    16.0.11026.35000
22. x-usersessionid: 
    ece4e392-c1a8-4498-ae8d-aaf8ef99cf27

Comment: This should work but we are seeing some reliability issues. 
Could you provide  the exact request response headers, group id, tenant id, owner id to diagnose further?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I have added the requested data to the initial post.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT any findings yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're an owner but not a member. Planner doesn't support that -- add yourself to the members collection as well.

Comment: Yes looks like this is the problem. The default groupify dialog in SP Online also adds users from the associated owner group to MS group members AND Owners.

Comment: Be carefull when adding members and owners programatically. You always need to add a user to members first! 
Otherwise the users will only be members even if you have added them to members before.